# How to change expected datasource property name in Spring

Tags: spring, oracle, jdbc

I would like to change the **expected** property name in Spring for data source from:

`spring.datasource.url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:151:xe`

to:

`com.foo.bar.spring.datasource.url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:151:xe`

i.e. have a certain prefix for all spring properties in my application.

Is that possible? If so, how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just too curious, why you need this?

Comment: We use Netflix Archaius for configuration resolution. The way we have our config loader designed it loads configuration from many lib-configs. Generally we try to have specific names for properties so that we can avoid name collision. `spring.datasource.url` should not but might collide with another property from another source.

Comment: You may think of redesigning the way the config loader works. I guess, you can conclude the prefix for the application. Otherwise you may potentially  try to find special treatment for the other common properties listed in https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

Answer (score 1):

Write a configuration class where you instantate your DataSource per @Bean annotation like this:

```
@Configuration
public MyConfig {

    @Bean(name = "dataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.foo.bar.spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource() {
       DataSource dataSource = DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
       return dataSource;
    }
 }
```

this should do the trick..

[see spring doc here:](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-a-datasource)

Comment: This is great but it their a way to say it across the board. As in all properties like spring.x.y now need to be com.foo.bar.spring.x.y?

Comment: hmm, with above approch all datsource properties need to have the prefix. The other properties like e.g. logging are still the same.